# Non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

In the following code, I am receiving an error stating: `Non-default argument follows default argument`.

Would anyone happen to know how to resolve this?

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, first_name=None, last_name=None, username=None,
                     password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email.')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        if first_name and last_name:
            potential_username = slugify(
                "{0} {1}".format(first_name, last_name))

            try:
                check_user = self.model.get(
                    username=potential_username).exists()
            except check_user.DoesNotExist:
                check_user = None

            if not check_user:
                username = potential_username

        user = self.model(email=email,
                          username=username,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, username,
                    password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, is_staff=False,
                                 is_superuser=False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, is_staff=True,
                                 is_superuser=True, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed

```
def _create_user(self, email, first_name=None, last_name=None, username=None,
                 password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
```

You are assignging defaults to `first_name`, `last_name` and `username` but not to `password`, `staff` etc. You will either have to change their order or you will need to assign defaults to the parameters that follow username.

Example:

```
def _create_user(self, email, 
 password, is_staff, is_superuser,
 first_name=None, last_name=None,
 username=None,**extra_fields):
```

Comment: What do you mean change their order?

Comment: Glad I could help.